# Should I paginate data query? Getting 5000 documents from firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Do I have to paginate the data query?

I need to send email notifications to 5000 users every day from firebase functions.

My first approach is:

1. Make a query to firestore to get every user who must receive notification, making a .where() get.
2. Send emails using a third party service.

how would you tell if you have to paginate the data? What would be a good practice?

**Edit**

Each document has 50 words.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you may have to explain more about "how would you tell if you have to paginate the data?".  The reasons I would think to paginate are that you might want to send batches of emails requests in parallel to your email service or the email service can't handle large batches.  I'm almost tempted to look into a microservices story.  Have one service that determines who should receive the emails and then pump those into PubSub with a subscriber that sends an email per message.

Comment: My initial concerns were on best practices because of the big size of the query.. What do you mean with "look into a microservices story"?

Comment: By microservices ... I was imagining breaking the puzzle into MANY smaller puzzles where each part is a "microservice".  For example, instead of reading the identities of ALL 5000 users and then processing 5000 users ... we would break this up into read each user record individually and then create a task for each user.  So it would be a fan-out .... you would use Pub/Sub to publish a message for each each user which would be received by a microservice that sends ONE email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large you configured your Cloud Functions instances to be, and how big your documents are, you may or may not **need** to paginate the results.

I typically prefer not to depend on such magic number though, so when I have more than a few thousand documents to process, I tend to process them in pages of a couple of hundred documents at a time.